# Can we run github actions inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, github-actions

Is it possible to run github actions inside docker container like jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two aspects:

1. can github actions run containers?
2. Can github actions run container *like jenkins*

To answer the former, by default Github actions do run in containers. From the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#the-components-of-github-actions):

> Your workflow contains one or more jobs which can run in sequential order or in parallel. Each job will run inside its own virtual machine runner, **or inside a container**, and has one or more steps that either run a script that you define or run an action, which is a reusable extension that can simplify your workflow.

(emphasis my own)

There is also a [dedicated page for creating container-based runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-docker-container-action)

For the latter part of the question, it's not quite clear what you mean by "like Jenkins", but the [Github Actions guide](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/migrating-from-jenkins-to-github-actions) should provide the relevant context.